# Meteor Keeps Giving Me An Unexpected String Error When Running My Package

Tags: meteor, telescope

I have been trying to add another static page to my "telescope-static-pages" package and whenever I tell Meteor where to add or update this package it seems to give me this error below:

The code seems right to me, but maybe I am missing something.

```
=> Errors while initializing project: While reading package from `/root/Telescope/packages/telescope-static-pages`:package.js:23:5: Unexpected 


api.add_files([
    'lib/client/templates/about_page.html',
    'lib/client/templates/about_link.html',
    'lib/client/about.js'
    'lib/client/templates/contact_page.html',
    'lib/client/templates/contact_link.html',
    'lib/client/contact.js'
  ], ['client']);

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a comma after `'lib/client/about.js'`

Comment: Thanks! Guess I just missed that comma! :) Sometimes you just need a second eye viewing the code.

Comment: Happens to the best of us!